Does the following submodule of a $\mathbb Z[t,t^{-1}]$ module have a complement?
Let $M = \oplus_{i\in \mathbb Z}  V^{(i)}$ where each $ V^{(i)} \cong \mathbb Q ^4 $. Consider $M$  as a  $\mathbb Z[t,t^{-1}]$ module where $t$ shifts coordinates one place to the right.
Let $e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4$ be a standard basis in $\mathbb Q^4$.  Let $e_j^{(i)}$ be the element  in $M$ whose $i$-th coordinate is $e_j$ and other coordinates are $0$.
Consider the following submodule $
N = \left\{\begin{array}{c|c}
e_1^{(i)}-e_3^{(i+1)} & \\
e_2^{(i)}-e_4^{(i+1)} & i \in \mathbb{Z} \\
e_2^{(i)}+e_4^{(i)}+e_3^{(i)}-e_1^{(i+1)} &
\end{array}\right\}
$
Question: I want to check if $N$ is a direct summand of $M$, i.e. does there exist a submodule $N'$ of $M$ such that $M= N \oplus N'$?
I tried to find such N', whenever I found an $N'$ such that the sum of $N'$ and $N$ is $M$, I always get $N$ and $N'$ having non-trivial intersection.
Where I come across this question: In this case, $M$ has some vector space structure (e.g. clearly $M$ is a vector space over $\mathbb Q$). I want to show that, if we consider $M$ as a  $\mathbb Z[t,t^{-1}]$ module, not every submodule has a complement.
Any ideas would be really appreciated. Thank you for reading.

Are you sure you don't want the ring to be $\Bbb{Q}[t,t^{-1}]$ instead of $\Bbb{Z}[t,t^{-1}]$? Not that it would necessarily be relevant here, but $\Bbb{Q}$ is indecomposable as a $\Bbb{Z}$-module, and any two non-zero $\Bbb{Z}$-submodules intersect.

I am answering the variant, where we look at modules over $R=\Bbb{Q}[t,t^{-1}]$. Simply because I think that mentioning $\Bbb{Z}[t,t^{-1}]$ was somewhat of a typo.

We have been given a submodule $N$ of the free $R$-module $M=R^4$. As $R$ is a PID, $N$ must be free. Indeed, we see that $N$ is freely generated by the three vectors
$$(1,0,-t,0),\qquad (0,1,0,-t)\qquad\text{and}\qquad (-t,1,1,1).$$
The theory around Smith normal forms suggests strongly to look at the common factors of the minors of the generator matrix (forgive me for using terminology from convolutional codes, where instead $R$ we similarly look at modules over
the ring of power series $\Bbb{F}_2[[t]]$)
$$
G(t)=\left(\begin{array}{rrrr}1&0&-t&0\\ 0&1&0&-t\\ -t&1&1&1\end{array}\right).
$$
We see that if we specialize $t=-1$, the resulting matrix in $\mathcal{M}_{3\times 4}(\Bbb{Q})$ has rank two only. In other words, $t+1$ is a factor of each and every
$3\times3$ minor of $G(t)$. It is straightforward to verify that $t+1$ is actually the greatest common divisor of the full size minors.
This immediately implies that the matrix $G(t)$ cannot be completed to a $4\times4$ matrix that would have as a determinant a unit of the ring $R$. Simply because $1+t$ is not a unit of $R$. OP's conjecture follows from this immediately. A complement, call it $N'$, would necessarily be a free $R$-module of rank one, but the above observation means $N\oplus N'$ cannot be all of $R^4$, for then the matrix gotten by adding a generator of $N'$ as the fourth row to $G(t)$ should have unit determinant.

In other words (specializing $t=2$), the argument is a lot like that showing that the free abelian subgroup $V$ of $\Bbb{Z}^4$ generated by  $(1,0,-2,0)$, $(0,1,0,-2)$ and $(-2,1,1,1)$ has no complement in $\Bbb{Z}^4$, because one of its invariant factors is $3$.
